# com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7, twelvemonkeys

I am using maven to build project which deploys on the tomcat server. The build process completed successfully but when i am trying to deploy the project on tomcat 7 its throwing error. 
I can see the twelemonkey-servlet.jar is present in the lib folder in WEB-INF.

pom.xml

```
      <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>




 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>3.06</version> 
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys</groupId>
        <artifactId>twelvemonkeys-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.08</version> 
    </dependency>
```

The build is successful but while deployment i am getting following exception

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@386d4852
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

please suggest solution if someone faced this problem before.

Answer (score 9):

Late answer, but I had the same problem today. I noticed the artifactId for the twelvemonkeys servlet has changed since version 3. Using the dependency below, it works for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```